# redirect new url in same page with ajax and spring

Tags: javascript, ajax, spring

i have some code ajax like this

```
    $.ajax({
        a :a,
        b : b,
        type : 'GET',
        method: 'GET',
        url   : "/report-join-promo/list",
        data : {a,b}

    });
```

and i have this script in my controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/list", method = RequestMethod.GET )
public String ReportJoinPromoList(@RequestParam(value = "a" ,required = false,defaultValue = "") String a ,
                                  @RequestParam(value = "b" ,required = false,defaultValue = "") String b ,
                                  Model model){

    return "pages/promo/report";
}
```

first url is http://localhost:8080/report/list 
and i want my url become to http://localhost:8080/report/list?a=valueofa&b=valueofb in same page but i can't solve this

Comment: You can append data with your url.

Comment: What wenr wrong with answer @Anggara Maha Putra ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are OK with HTML5 only, you can use `history` API to change URL, without going to server. So, your code now will look like:

```
var a = 'Param1';
var b = 'Param2';
$.ajax({
    url : "/report-join-promo/list",
    type : 'GET',
    data : {
        a: a,
        b: b
    },
    success: function(response) {
         // Your code
    },
    error: function(xhr) {
        // Your code
    }
});
if(history.pushState) {
    history.pushState({}, 'Page Title', 'list?a=' + encodeURIComponent(a) + '&b=' + encodeURIComponent(b));
}
```

A nice example of this API is demonstrated at [ASPSNIPPETS](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/HTML5-History-pushState-function-Tutorial-in-JavaScript-and-jQuery-with-example.aspx). For more detail read the [MDN DOC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API)